# My app is 'installing' whenever a new user runs my app for THEIR first time

Tags: wix, wix3.9

I have a Wix 3.9 install setup.  The app is installed *PERMACHINE* via the *InstallScope* property.  Whenever I try to run the app as a new user, it starts installing some drivers that I included, and has an install dialog that pops up.  After 10-15 seconds, the dialog goes away and everything works fine.  The dialog pops up the FIRST TIME ONLY that any user that isn't the installing user runs the app.  The installing user acts as expected.  Might anyone know how to get rid of this annoying install dialog?

Comment: Does this happen when you run it from a shortcut your installer created?

Comment: This is called auto repair, and is part of [resiliency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371230). You can find out what component is detected in a faulty state by looking in the event logs, and can generate verbose text logs for it by [setting a registry key to enable logging](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging). Those will help you diagnose the behavior.

Comment: I actually thought it has more to do with advertised shortcuts, see here  - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11776530/1632576

Comment: They are related; advertised shortcuts are one of the entry points that invoke the resiliency check that can result in performing auto repair.

Comment: @DanG is it advertised? (if yes - i think that removing the advertise property from the shortcut should solve this)