# Wix: Shortcut open file location button is disabled

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I am using WiX for an installation project. I have a shortcut to my executable file on the desktop. When I go to the properties of shortcut the button `Open file location` is disabled. How do I make the button set to enable?
Here is my code:

```
<File Id="App.exe" Name="App.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\App.exe">                          
    <Shortcut Id="AppDesktop" Directory="DesktopFolder" 
                              Name="App" Icon="Icon.ico" 
                              IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" 
                              WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION"/>
</File>
```

Comment: Good answer from philselmer. In cases where you install user data to the user-profile or HKCU settings, an advertised shortcut helps to ensure that the settings and data make it onto the system for each user. Do you install user-specific files and registry keys?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Yes, I install the user-specific files and registry keys. It seems that it will be necessary to leave everything as it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using an advertised shortcut.  If you do not need this functionality, you should remove `Advertise="yes"` from the Shortcut tag.

For more information about the difference between the two, there is a fantastic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228008/2487257) to a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11776023/2487257).