# Using Python to search program installed on server

Tags: python, windows, advertised-shortcut

I would like to use Python to search Projectwise (a document management program). I thought this would work:

```
import subprocess  
subprocess.call("Projectwise.exe")
```

However, it seems that Projectwise is not installed locally on my work computer. I cannot open the original file location from the shortcut. It is probably installed over all the office computers. Is it still possible to invoke Projectwise within Python?

edit: I have tried to find the application location, [but the properties window doesn't show where the shortcut leads to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3RcH.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: inspect the shortcut you would normally use to open the program and see where it points, then use that path as the argument to `subprocess.call`

Comment: have u try to inform full path from exe?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of the program shortcut's properties window. I am not sure how to view the path from here

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a python problem: https://superuser.com/questions/129416/windows-7-finding-location-of-installed-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the program uses an [advertised shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776023/advertised-shortcuts-vs-non-advertised-shortcuts-in-windows-setup-project). I suggest you run the application via the shortcut, and use Task Manager to find the location of the program while it is running.

Then, use that path as the argument to `subprocess.call`:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call("C:\Path\To\Projectwise.exe")
```

Comment: I found the path and it successfully opened the program. Thank you everyone for your help.